# Requesting for Location Services Android

Tags: android

I am using this code to for user to activate the location services. I want to show user dialog to accept to enable location services then redirect them to the LOCATION_SETTINGS Page. But Without the user accepting it from user it redirects to location settings.

```
if(lm==null)
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
try{
    gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}catch(Exception ex){}
try{
    network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}catch(Exception ex){}

if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled){
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setMessage(this.getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled));
    dialog.setPositiveButton(this.getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            //get gps
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton(this.getString(R.string.Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you try to enable the location.

You can show a dialog to enable the location instead of redirect them to LOCATION_SETTING page.

Step by step process.

First you need to set a GoogleApiClient and implements GoogleApiClient CallBackMethods.

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();   
}
```

CallBack Methods

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("OnConnected", "Connection successful");
    settingsrequest();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}
```

As soon as the googleapiclient connects, onconnected method will invoke and settingsRequest method will call.

```
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
LocationRequest locationRequest;


public void settingsrequest() {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);
    locationRequest.setExpirationDuration(20000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS: {
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
                }
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                // requests here.
                break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MainTab.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

status.startResolutionForResult(MainTab.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) will show a dialog requesting location.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
   // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this) will set a listener for the location cahnged.

As the location changed onLocationChanged method will invoke.

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      prevLocation  = location;
      //Do you work
}
```

**Hope this will helps you.**